# Build a function that sends mail by gmail c#

Tags: c#

```
 public void SendMail(string Subject, string Body, MailAddress To)
    // מטודה מקבלת פרטי מייל בודד ושולחת אותו
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("israel.nahum@gmail.com");
        var toAddress = To;
        string fromPassword = "46798513";
        string subject = Subject;
        string body = Body;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

What I do is actually get a few miles from the List Box, all mail sent into this function, the function reaches the last line of sending the SMTP and then returns an error! What could be the problem function? Has a proposal how to write it down otherwise please I need help!

Comment: A lot of people didn't notice that .NET 4.0 changed SmtpClient so now both it and MailMessage implement IDisposable. Both should be in using blocks. This is probably not causing the exception, but would be a good change to make if you're using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Israel, add a try/catch in the part where you call Send and look at the exception thrown, it will tell you EXACTLY what the problem is.

BTW, I hope that's not your real password or I am going to hack your account and then take over the world.

Comment: This Old password ..
You can add me to code the lines I do not know exactly where to place them

Comment: @Israel: this line: {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
change it to: {
            try {smtp.Send(message);} catch(Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);}
        } 
This will tell you what the error is. Unfortunately I can test this for you but something tells me that your issue might be related to the incorrect port being used or the wrong authentication method.

Comment: @Israel Show the stack trace as well, that message doesn't tell me much except that the exception occurred in your Form on line 269, which is probably where you call the method to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Gmail SMTP port is 465, at least that's what [they](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77659) say.

Answer (score 0):

Try not configuring a port and just using the default (25 I believe) that has worked for me in the past.